# Doctrine migration couldn`t find non-existed class

Tags: symfony, doctrine, migration, doctrine-1.2, doctrine-migrations

I use `doc:generate-migrations-diff`to generate migration classes located in `lib/migrations/`. You already might know, that `doc:generate-migrations-...` tasks create some files in tmp directory. I had some problems with it and i delete all doctrine help files from tmp dir. 
And now when I execute `doc:generate-migrations-diff` it fails with this message: `Couldn't find class ToPrfxProduct2Site`, I have `Product2Site` class, but there is no `ToPrfxProduct2Site`.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, i figured this out. Generating of migrations is based on existing models, so first try to find models that dont exists in your schema. For me there was `Product2Site`, `Product2SiteTable' and`BaseProduct2Site` models. Just delete this files and everything will be fine.